# magento 2 override a functionality compared with magento 1

Tags: price, magento2, catalog, overrides

In magento 1 we have local - community - core areas inside app->code folder. When you want to override a functionality placing code with same names in local or community will do the job.

working in magento 2,
I saw only one folder inside the `app->code` and it is magento. If we want to create an adjustment in price (eg: [calculator.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Pricing/Adjustment/Calculator.php) ) do we have to re-write core files or we have to work in another way?.

If I create a module in `app->code->magento->vendorname` to rewrite pricecalculation in catalog, which structure do I have to create in order to change the value and give magento 2 the parameter to let the application know that I want to override the catalog price?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento2 You can overwrite using **preference**. 
Example:

**in di.xml**

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="core/class" type="your/local/class" />
</config>
```

But you should avoid this overwrite using preference because of rewrite conflict.

In Magento1 have rewrite conflict issue, So Magento2 overcome this issue using **plugin** [Click here for more information about plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Try plugin than rewrite any class.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know class rewrite its potential conflict changes and not recommended at all if you can avoid it.

Preferable solution is use [plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) instead.